# Database choice: frequently querying 2nd degree connections

Tags: mysql, facebook-graph-api, database-schema, social-networking, database-performance

My web app needs to ALWAYS query 2nd degree connections. Each user has say 200 friends & those friends have 200 friends each. I could use some help in determining the right database (and table structure) to make this web app fast & responsive.

**Business logic**: Users search their 1st & 2nd degree connections to get a list of other users who use a specific service (stored in one column as *unsigned int*). That's the only functionality of this app.

**Table structure**:

- User Table: User_ID (pk), Facebook_ID (sk), Name, Specific-service, Location
- Relationship Table: still undecided.

**Question**: I read many posts & searched the web for "social networking database design". However, these applications feel much different than mine. I will have many users (+10 mil) but a small database & run only one query as described in business logic.

**Additional info**: Users can register (& subsequently log-in) only using their Facebook account. Their friends will be invited (via Facebook) to also register. The *Relationship Table* will be populated once friends register (only active/not-blocked/not-pending friends). Thus I can get rid of "friendship status" column from *Relationship Table*.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that has two ids in it; it will define a 'Friend'.  Is this relationship symmetric?  That is, if A is a friend of B, is B a friend of A?  Well, I will assume there are 2 rows when both occur.

Then

```
CREATE TABLE Friends (
    user1 ...,
    user2 ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(user1, user2),
    INDEX(      user2, user1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT a.name, c.name
    FROM Users AS a
    JOIN Friends AS ab  ON ab.user1 = a.user_id
    JOIN Users AS b  ON b.user_id = ab.user2
    JOIN Friends AS bc  ON bc.user1 = b.user_id
    JOIN Users AS c  ON c.user_id = bc.user2
    WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

Comment: Yes the design is symmetric & there are no other options (like Followers, Blocked contacts etc).

But my real question is, will this design be efficient when I perform the query to find 2nd degree friends?

Comment: If everything is cached, a thousand 2nd degree friends should take well under a second.  Even if not fully cached, it might take only a second.

Comment: Could you also please comment from your experience on which database to use? I mean should I go for graph database or RDBMS?

Comment: (I know nothing about any "graph database".  My expertise is in helping with MySQL, a RDBMS.)

Comment: @NeoSplit which database did you end up using for this?